# image disappears below 640px resolution in wordpress using avada theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, media-queries

I have a sticky image in website page, the site is made using wordpress and avada theme, the image disappears when width resolution goes below 640px.

I tried using custom classes and media queries like this:

```
@media only screen  
and (max-device-width : 640px) {
    .metaverso-img a img {
        width: 60px;
    }
}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 640px) 
and (max-device-width : 768px) {
    .metaverso-img a img{
        width: 80px;
    }
}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
    .metaverso-img a img{
        width: 100px;
    }
}
```

The last two rules work fine but the first one doesn't, even if I edit the queries resolution and i set different intervals, for example: 460-768 it still disappears below 640.

What can I do?

Comment: The first thing I see is that you double the numbers. You have 640 twice. Try to use for the first resolution 640, and for the second 641 to 768. Then 769 to 1024. The classes look identical. perhaps there is another problem. Can you provide a link to the live site?

Comment: I tried 640 for the first and 641 for the second but it doesn't work either.

Comment: @Azu the website is: "koncept.it" and the image is the qr code in top right corner